# When trying to create a cipher, how do you go about changing the characters in a string to integers

Tags: c, cs50

What I am trying to ask is when you are coding a cipher and you are asking for user input. How would you go about changing the characters in the string to numbers so that you could plug them into a formula and then get another letter out.

```
    string s = get_string("Plain Text:");

    while (s[a] != '\0')
    {
        if (isalpha(s[a]))
        {
            for (c = 0, e = strlen(s); c < e; c++)
            {
                if (isupper(s[a]))
                {
                    printf("C\n");
                    a++;
                }
                if (islower(s[a])) // (x=(?+(argv[1][i]))%26) This is the formula, the ? is where im trying to figure out how to change characters into numbers and then back in characters
                {
                    printf("c\n");
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }                    
    }
```

The 'printf' were to make sure that the code was checking for lower or upper case properly. If im not mistaken i'd need 2 formulas with different ranges in order for one to be upper and the other to be lower with that i would be able to plug them both into one cipher formula. Im pretty sure that you could also do without the whole check if its upper or lower but I dont really understand how you would go about creating the range or the loop so that it always stay with in alphabetical characters whether it be capital or lower case.

Comment: The characters in a string in C *are* integers (their exact type is `char`, which is an integer).

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about CS50 Caesar Cipher, you can see the formula there. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63568354/cs50-caesar-cipher-giving-incorrect-output-pset2/63568526#63568526

Comment: Step 1: `(s[a] - 'A') ` is the offset from `'A'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `char` type is an 8-bit integer. So a string is an array of 8-bit integers.

Because you mention a formula that applies `c % 26` to the character values, I'm assuming that you are only interested in ASCII text for this exercise. If you care about non-ASCII encodings, the whole approach will need to change. You can't do byte-by-byte analysis with strings in general. For example, in UTF8, some glyphs will span more than one byte, and in UTF16, each glyph is at least two bytes.

The upper-case A–Z characters are in the range 65..90 and the lower-case a-z characters are in the range 97..122. So you will want to get those values in the range 0..25 before applying an arithmetic formula to them.

You can do this like this:

- When `isupper(s[a])` is true: `int c = s[a] - 65;`
- When `islower(s[a])` is true: `int c = s[a] - 97;`

Then apply your formula.

As an aside, normally when doing arithmetic with `char`s, you'll need to pay special care to values between 128 and 255, because `char *` is not a pointer to an array of **unsigned** values. And with Unicode strings, some of your glyphs may span more than one byte each. But because we're only considering ASCII strings, this doesn't apply here.

Comment: *The upper-case A–Z characters are in the range 65..90...*  That's only true for the ASCII character set.  It's not true in general.

Comment: Absolutely true. Since @Frank's question involves a formula that applies `c % 26` to each character value, I'm assuming an ASCII constraint but you're right that it's worth pointing out explicitly. I'll add that assumption to the answer.

Comment: I assume you would add the subtracted number back to the formula or do you not need to?

Comment: Yes, you'd want to add the offset back in after doing your cypher, assuming you want the encoded characters to be alphabetic. (On the other hand you might want to use numbers, or switch between upper and lower case, or use non-alphanumeric symbols, or something else.)